# Which is the file format of ~/.gitconfig?

Tags: git, terminal, config

I would like to format my `~/.gitconfig` file, but I don't know the file type. Is it `toml` or `yml` or something else?

Do indentations matter? What structure does it expect?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What do you mean by "kind of format" exactly? It's a configuration text file.

Comment: It has no specific standard format. It's a format that git expects, that's all. It's similar to an ini file, but not quite.

Comment: I would like to know what tool I could use to be able to format the text of the file.

Comment: `what tool I could use able to format the text of the file` any text editor will be fine....

Comment: I mean something like prettier for yml or toml... @KamilCuk

Comment: It is pretty close to [INI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) format.

Comment: The premise of plain text files is that they don't have any formatting, just human-readable characters and end of line (EOL) characters. To structure it like yml or some other file type would violate convention

Comment: @EliazBobadilla it's best to keep the question focused on figuring out its format. Once the file format is established, then it's good to ask for tools that can respect that file format.

Comment: @mfaani No?  Resource and tool requests are [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)(point 3).

Comment: this is a good question, when i paste gitconfig code to wiki, the code need be highlight, so how can i set the format for wiki ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Which is the file format of ~/.gitconfig?

The format is described [in documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_configuration_file). It has no specific "standard" format. It's just a format that Git expects. It is similar to an [ini file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file), but not quite - there are subsections and values with quotations.

> what tool I could use able to format the text of the file

Just do not indent sections and comments and indent any other lines. You can write such a program in `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: If you use vim/neovim you can select all the text and then press `=`.

Answer (score 3):

follow by wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#cite_note-4
and official doc: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_configuration_file

it is really totally ini file, u can use ini format it.